# Ggplot - How to add 2 different error bars?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I try to make a bar plot with 2 different confidence intervals - one for the proportion of females at a sample and the other for the proportion of males. Each category has of course two different confidence intervals, how can I make this graph with only 2 and not 4 confidence intervals?

```
  ggplot(data, aes(x= GENDER)) + 
  geom_bar(aes(y = (..count..)/sum(..count..)), stat="count", fill=c("deeppink","deepskyblue"), alpha=0.7) +
  scale_y_continuous("Percent",labels = scales::percent)+
  geom_text(aes(label = scales::percent((..count..)/sum(..count..)),
                y= ((..count..)/sum(..count..))), stat="count",vjust = 5) +
  geom_errorbar (aes(ymin = ymin1, ymax =ymax1), width=0.4, colour = "red", alpha =0.9, size= 1.3)+
  geom_errorbar (aes(ymin = ymin2, ymax =ymax2), width=0.4, colour = "red", alpha =0.9, size= 1.3)
```

[image: how the graph looks like right now]

Thanks ahead!

Answer (score 0):

You only need to call geom_errorbar once, where ymin and ymax are vectors. The way you've coded it, ggplot is plotting both error bars in both positions because it is expecting a vector of positions for ymin and ymax equal to the number of bars in your plot. E.g.

```
ymin = c(ymin1,ymin2)
ymax = c(ymax1,ymax2)
ggplot(data, aes(x= GENDER)) + 
  geom_bar(aes(y = (..count..)/sum(..count..)), stat="count", fill=c("deeppink","deepskyblue"), alpha=0.7) +
  scale_y_continuous("Percent",labels = scales::percent)+
  geom_text(aes(label = scales::percent((..count..)/sum(..count..)),
                y= ((..count..)/sum(..count..))), stat="count",vjust = 5) +
  geom_errorbar (aes(ymin = ymin, ymax =ymax), width=0.4, colour = "red", alpha =0.9, size= 1.3)
```

Comment: My data frame has 116 samples. When I try to insert a vector of 2 values - there's an error  - 'Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (116)', and on the other hand - there's no point at inserting a vector with 116 values - what should I do?

Comment: To solve this, you need to put the data in the bar and text geometries and take it out of the call to `ggplot()`, so you'd need to have `ggplot() + geom_bar(data=data, aes(x=GENDER, y=...) + geom_text(data=data, aes(x=GENDER, y=...)` and then the rest of the plotting should work.

Answer (score 0):

You could also manage the data ahead of time with `dplyr::summarise()` to make a dataset that only has one observation per group that has whatever summary values you want.  This makes the plotting code a bit more streamlined.  I did this on the `Chile` data from the `carData` package

```
data("Chile", package="carData")
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
Chile %>% 
  group_by(sex) %>% 
  dplyr::summarise(n_g= n(), 
            n = sum(!is.na(Chile$sex)),
            prop = n_g/n, 
            ymin = binom.test(n_g, n)$conf.int[1], 
            ymax = binom.test(n_g, n)$conf.int[2]) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=sex, y=prop, ymin=ymin, ymax=ymax) )+ 
    geom_bar(stat="identity", alpha=.7, fill=c("deeppink","deepskyblue")) + 
    geom_errorbar(width=.4, colour="red", alpha=.9, size=1.3) + 
    geom_text(aes(label = scales::percent(prop)), vjust = 5)
```

[image]

---

**EDIT**

changed to use `prop.test()` as in the OP's comment.

```
data("Chile", package="carData")
 library(dplyr)
 library(ggplot2)
 data <- Chile
 data <- data %>% rename("GENDER" = "sex")
 
 data %>% 
   group_by(GENDER) %>% 
   dplyr::summarise(n_g= n(), 
                    n = sum(!is.na(data$GENDER)),
                    prop = n_g/n,  
                    ymin = prop.test(n_g, n, p=.7, alternative="greater")$conf.int[1], 
                    ymax = prop.test(n_g, n, p=.7, alternative="greater")$conf.int[2]) %>% 
   ggplot(aes(x=GENDER, y=prop, ymin=ymin, ymax=ymax) )+ 
   geom_bar(stat="identity", alpha=.7, fill=c("deeppink","deepskyblue")) + 
   geom_errorbar(width=.4, colour="red", alpha=.9, size=1.3) + 
   geom_text(aes(label = scales::percent(prop)), vjust = 5)
```

[image]

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the answer!
2 things:
1. I've calculated the confidence intervals and i got [0 to 0.26] for males and [0.73 to 1] for females. How do I present these values at my graph? I didn't really get what you did there with the binom test...
2. I got my graph 90 degrees rotated, coord_flip() didn't help me. What should I do?

Comment: You would need to replace `Chile` with the name of your data frame, `data`, and `group_by(sex)` with your gender variable, `group_by(GENDER)`.  Then, in the line `n = sum(!is.na(Chile$sex)),` should be changed to `n = sum(!is.na(data$GENDER))`.  Otherwise, it should work.  I used `binom.test()` to calculate the confidence intervals for each of the groups, so the `ymin` and `ymax` values in the summarised data will be the confidence intervals for each group.

Comment: And how do I flip the graph?

Comment: Updated to use `prop.test()` the way you've specified it to calculate the confidence interval.  I also changed the name of the data to `data` and the name of `sex` to `GENDER`.

Comment: If you've tried `coord_flip()` and it didn't work, you could try swapping the `x` and `y` variables.

Comment: Thank you, you helped me alot!